# Displacement strategy for (Computer) Cache

Tags: cache

[Here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache), under displacement strategies, the following is written (Unfortunately, only in German available):

> Laszlo Belady's method of displacing the memory area that will not be
> accessed for the longest time is optimal. However, it is applicable
> only when the complete program flow is known in advance (i.e., it is a
> so-called offline procedure, in contrast to FIFO and LRU, which are
> online procedures). However, the program flow is almost never known in
> advance; therefore, the optimal procedure cannot be used in practice.
> However, the optimal algorithm can serve as a comparison for other
> procedures.

I wonder why the program has to be known in advance to make this routine an optimal method. Sure, I understand, that, sometimes, when a memory not used for a while, will be thrown out but needed immediately afterwards, is not optimal but this behaviour is the most reasonable and hence, "optimal"? It's actually not about the wording, I really wonder this method isn't as good as it seems.

Comment: that whole article has honestly deserved the "this article lacks references" warning at the beginning.

Comment: Cache is limited and is based on what came before, not what comes next.  The least used cache memory block may or may not be required now, so knowledge of the best block to trash would improve performance, but that knowledge has a cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Laszlo Belady's method of displacing the memory area that **will** not be accessed for the longest time is optimal

For you to know *when* something *will be accessed in the future*, you need to know when your program accesses which part of memory.

The author of the wikipedia article confuses this with knowledge of program flow, which is not the same thing (memory access locations / patterns is *one* of the things that arise from the program flow).

Comment: Thank you, so is it just wrong or has it to be different? Tbh, I'm not sure about the statement.

Comment: it's wrong. You don't need knowledge about the future program flow, you need knowledge about the future memory access.